# How to assign multiple api views to single endpoint in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model named **Article** and a few api views for it. They are **divided** for diffrent purposes (for example ArticleUpdateAPI class for UPDATE http method, ArticleDeleteAPI for DELETE method etc). In urls.py they are separated to diffrent endpoints (aritcle/pk/update, /article/pk/delete etc).

As I know, it's **not good** practice to build endpoint like this, so I want to bind them to single url and use diffrent classes for handling diffrent http methods. Is it possible and how? Examples are below

ArticleAPI.py

```
class ArticlePostAPI(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly
    ]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "comment": CommentSerializer.data
        }, status=201)


class ArticleRetrieveAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]


class ArticleListAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    queryset = Article.objects.order_by('number', 'headline')
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]


class ArticleUpdateAPI(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]

    lookup_field = 'pk'

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()

        if request.user != instance.author:
            return Response({
               "errors": "Logged in user and author must be same"
            }, status=403)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...

    # Article API

    path('article/post/', ArticlePostAPI.as_view(), name='article_creation'),
    path('article/<int:pk>/', ArticleRetrieveAPI.as_view(), name='article_retrieve'),
    path('article/', ArticleListAPI.as_view(), name='article_list'),
    path('article/<int:pk>/update/', ArticleUpdateAPI.as_view(), name='article_update'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ModelViewSet` for simplifying it.

Using this you can perform all http method actions with a single url and single view.

```
from rest_framework import viewsets


class ArticleView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
```

urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'articles', views.ArticleView, basename='articles')
```

here

```
GET - /articles/ - gives list of all articles
GET - /articles/id/ - gives one object
POST - /articles/ - creates an article
PUT - /articles/id/ - updates an article
PATCH - /articles/id/ - partially updates an article
DELETE - /articles/id/ - deletes an article
```